# Excel VBA: Delete and Add Allow User to Edit Ranges of a Table that's dynamic

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble adding the Table that is on the worksheet to AllowEditRanges. I know the syntax to add it like so: `ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Range1", Range:=Range("Table1353")`, but I will be creating new worksheets periodically, and each worksheet with have one table. I need it to grab the table on the worksheet and add it. Not sure if the code below is the way to do it but I am getting a debug error on code line `ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="TableSort", Range:=.DataBodyRange` - "Object Variable and With block variable not set." Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Sub AddNewAER()

Dim aer As AllowEditRange
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0
For Each aer In ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges
aer.Delete
Next aer


With tbl
ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="TableSort", Range:=.DataBodyRange
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tbl` is declared as an ListObject but not `Set` before using. Hence the error.

`Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")` before with statement.

Also,

`tbl` itself is ListObject so `tbl.ListObject` will not work.

Do this:

`With tbl
    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="TableSort", Range:=.DataBodyRange
 End With`

Comment: Thanks. I updated by code and I am still getting that debug error on line `ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="TableSort", Range:=.DataBodyRange`. I am trying to avoid calling the table name. I don't want to change the macro every time I create a new table. Should I be doing a For Each statement for that? I tried and I still get the debug error on that line. Thanks.

Comment: SInce you have only one table in a worksheet you can use `Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)`